# Angularjs: compile directive using current scope value inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a page that has compiled template. The problem is that template is compiled in both loop against alldata[1] on both case.

```
var app = angular.module("bcreport", []);

app.controller("bcreport_controller", function($scope, $compile) {
  var alldata = [{'name':'tom','age':34},{'name':'alice','age':24}];

  for (var i=0; i<alldata.length; i++)
  {
    $scope.name = alldata[i]['name'];
    $scope.age = alldata[i]['age'];

    angular.element(document.querySelector("#container")).append($compile("<bcr></bcr>")($scope));
  }
});

app.directive("bcr", function () {

   var directiveDefinitionObject = {
     restrict:'E',
     transclude:true,
     scope:true,
     templateUrl: "templates/report_template.html",
     replace:true,
   };

   return directiveDefinitionObject;

});
```

Comment: Have you tried assembling (concatenating) the template string and then compiling it outside the for-loop?  In your example, $compile will be executed for each object in the array.

*Edit* Also, its generally a poor decision to perform DOM manipulation inside of a controller.  It might be better to add a pre-compile, post-compile, or link function to your directive to handle this instead.

Comment: I need to compile the template for each object in array. I followed this technique so that I could add more data inside object and compile.Template contains lengthy html code and the object array is also bigger. Can you show me some examples, how pre-compile or post-compile or link function works in my case as I am new to angularjs.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your use case based on that description.  Could you supply an example of how you're adding data after it's already been compiled?

Comment: No I just have a pre-built object array which is much larger than the above sample. Is there any way I can compile on each loop against each object value?

Comment: You don't need to compile each object individually.  You could simply have a concatenated string of your <bcr> elements and compile them all at once.  For example, if you concatenated a string like: '<bcr></bcr><bcr></bcr>' and the '$compile' instruction would compile all of them within the context of the '$scope' you pass in.  I still feel like the root cause of the issue you're having here is that you're trying to do DOM manipulation in a controller instead of doing it within the directive (since a directive can have its own scope).

Comment: can you show me snippet, how can I do this?